ModelMapper map wrong Id when running Save method of JpaRepository
I'm using Hibernate for my Spring Boot project. So I have problem when using Save method of JpaRepository. When I try to save an new item Answer, ModelMapper wrongly thinks that a property of Answer is questionId as the answerId of the Answer object, so instead of saving a new Answer item, it updates an existing Answer item with answerId = questionId that I entered.
Here is my Answer and Question model:
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Answer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int answerId;
    private String answer;
    private String status;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "questionId", nullable = false)
    private Question question;
}

@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Question {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int questionId;
    private String question;
    private String questionType;
    private String status;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "questions", cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private Set<Quiz> quizzes;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Answer> answers;
}

My Dto
public class AnswerDTO {

    @NotEmpty
    private String answer;

    @NotEmpty
    private String status;

    @NotNull
    private Integer questionId;


}

My ModelMaper
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

        // ignore null attributes on the source object on copying
        modelMapper.getConfiguration()
                .setSkipNullEnabled(true);      
        return modelMapper;
    }
}

AnswerBuilder:
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AnswerBuilder {

    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;
    public Answer build(AnswerDTO dto) {
        Answer model = modelMapper.map(dto, Answer.class);
        return model;
    }

    public Optional<AnswerDTO> build(Answer domain) {
        AnswerDTO dto = modelMapper.map(domain, AnswerDTO.class);
        return Optional.of(dto);
    }

    public Answer build(AnswerDTO dto, Answer domain) {
        modelMapper.map(dto, domain);
        return domain;
    }
}

and this is my create Service:
public int createNewAnswer(AnswerDTO dto) {
        return Stream.of(dto)
                .map(answerBuilder::build)
                .map(answerRepository::save)
                .map(Answer::getAnswerId)
                .findFirst()
                .get();
    }

I try using setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT) for ModelMapper but all the questionId in Answer list turn to null. And I can't save new Item. Here is the error:
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'question_id', table 'SPRINGTEST.dbo.answer'; column does not allow nulls.

I'm struggling with this problem for a morning so I really hope you guys can help. Sorry for my bad English

First, you need to change your matching strategy to Strict. Your questionId is becomes null is because the ModelMapper doesn't know how to map questionId to Question entity.
there might be a better solution but here is what i'll do it:
In your AnswerBuilder:
//create an id constructor for Question if you're going for option 2
public class Question {
  Question(long id){
    this.id = id
  }
  // rest of code...
}

@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AnswerBuilder {
    private final QuestionRepository questionRepository; //inject the repo if you're going for option 1
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;
    public Answer build(AnswerDTO dto) {
      Answer model = modelMapper.map(dto, Answer.class);
      // option 1:
      questionRepository.findById(dto.getQuestionId())
        .ifPresent(question -> model.setQuestion(question));

      //option 2:
      model.setQuestion(new Question(dto.getQuestionId()));
      return model;
    }
    // rest of code...
}

You don't have to always use functional programming 'way'
public int createNewAnswer(AnswerDTO dto) {
  return Stream.of(dto)
          .map(answerBuilder::build)
          .map(answerRepository::save)
          .map(Answer::getAnswerId)
          .findFirst()
          .get();
}

Some code can be done imperatively and more concise.
public int createNewAnswer(AnswerDTO dto) {
  Answer answer = answerBuilder.build(dto);
  return answerRepository.save(answer).getAnswerId();
}


Thank you @Shah Erhan. The questionId was still null in the getAllAnswers API, but I did the same solution in the other build method, and it worked. You are the savior!

A simpler solution could be creating a TypeMap for conversion dto to entity and define the specific field mappings, in this way you manage the mapping  between dto and entity fields.
For exmpl i did skip the answerId field from automapper and each time i was using the AutoMapper conversion, the answerId field was assigned the default type value (which is 0 for int in this case) and the save worked fine.
check below the changes i made:
@Bean
public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    modelMapper.getConfiguration()
               .setSkipNullEnabled(true);

    // Create a type map for AnswerDTO to Answer entity converting 
    TypeMap<AnswerDTO, Answer> typeMap = modelMapper.createTypeMap(AnswerDTO.class, Answer.class);

    // skip the answerId field from auto mapping
    typeMap.addMappings(mapper -> mapper.skip(Answer::setAnswerId));

    return modelMapper;
}

